# iOS receipt validation - is there any point in doing it every launch?

Tags: ios, validation, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I've implemented both the iOS6 and iOS7-style in-app-purchase receipt validation code. (Big thanks to Robot Media and its RMStore code on Github for guidance!) I'm validating every time a purchase is made or refreshed. I'm wondering whether it makes any sense to repeat this validation every time the app runs.

I can see how this makes sense with the iOS6 style, since it calls Apple's validation server, which may be spoofed sometimes and sometimes not.  But if I understand correctly, the iOS7 style simply checks the app receipt in the bundle for ids of the purchased products.  If this file doesn't change, I can't see how it helps to keep checking it.  Does it change?  Does the system tweak it now and then?  Does Cydia?

While we're at it:  Is there any point in doing BOTH iOS6 and iOS7 validation styles?  I figure it couldn't hurt, since I've implemented both.  Maybe another way to put this is:  Is the iOS7 style un-beaten?  And is the iOS6 style a decided failure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering whether it makes any sense to repeat this validation every time the app runs.

If it makes you feel safer and doesn't hurt the user experience...

> Does [the receipt] change? Does the system tweak it now and then?

The receipt changes with each in-app purchase and there's nothing in the documentation that states that it can't change for other reasons.

> Does Cydia?

No idea.

> Is the iOS7 style un-beaten?

On jailbroken devices, one only needs to know where the verification code is to patch it.

> And is the iOS6 style a decided failure?

It's deprecated at the very least.